# Есть ли отличия в употреблении слова "опыт" с родительным и дательным падежом?

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи, управление

Посмотрел на Грамоте, что словарь управления разрешает использовать оба падежа

> ОПЫТ [в разных значениях] чего / в чём / по чему / с кем. Опыт
> строительства; Потом появились на столе бумажки с крупными каракулями
> — первые её опыты в письме (Гл.); Имеется опыт по использованию новых
> материалов; Опыты с кроликами и морскими свинками.

Мне же дательный падеж немного режет ухо. Предлог "по" кажется каким-то лишним, инородным. Хочется заменить

**Имеется опыт по использованию новых материалов**

на

**Имеется опыт использования новых материалов**

Насколько использование этих падежей равнозначно? Не является ли родительный падеж более приоритетным? Иногда хочется использовать дательный падеж, чтобы убрать нагромождения родительных в конструкциях вида

**Он уехал для передачи опыта использования оборудования.**

Но есть сомнения в корректности и благозвучности такой замены.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У слова ***опыт*** два основных значения:  (1) совокупность **знаний, навыков, умения.** (2) Воспроизведение какого-л. явления или наблюдение нового явления с целью изучения, исследования; **эксперимент.**

В значении (1)  ***опыт*** может определяться как родительным беспредложным, так дательным предложным падежом: *опыт (какой?) использования* (Р.п.), **опыт  по использованию** (Д.п.).

*Имеется **опыт использования** новых материалов. Уехал для передачи **опыта по использованию** новых материалов.*

Таким образом, Д.п. желательно применять в **сложных** конструкциях.

В значении  «эксперимент» слово ***опыт*** лучше сочетается с Д.п.:  *Начался **опыт** (эксперимент) **по обучению** в школе детей с 6 лет.  Учёный проводил **опыт по передаче** энергии «по воздуху».*

В Нацкорпусе приводится 195 примеров, в которых используется предлог ПО (опыт по…). Следовательно,  Д.п. совсем не лишний в этой теме.

Answer (score 0):

Можно **поставить опыт по** использованию новых материалов (или опыт по превращению свинца в золото) но едва ли можно такой "опыт по" (как и историю или факт) "иметь" - это стилистически неудачный пример употребления, в лучшем случае канцеляризм. У разных значений слова "опыт" разная предложно-падежная сочетаемость.

Comment: Но у Розенталя в словаре именно "Имеется опыт по использованию новых материалов" http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?all=x&word=%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82

Comment: Возможно, в его времена так писали в газетах (он приводил реальные примеры), но если сейчас эту фразу набрать гуглом, то в результатах находится главным образом  "опыт чего". "Опыт по"  появляется при двойном управлении, когда между словом "опыт" и предлогом "по" присутствует существительное или имя в притяжательном смысле: "Опыт _учителей_ по использованию новых инфомационных технологий". Я по-прежнему воспринимаю тот пример как канцеляризм.